# Command Flow in C, function call after printf

Tags: c, command-line

So I have this super simple C code here taking a user input and prints it out followed by a "T-Plus" while loop. In this case I chose a random name for testing "whoa", but the while loop is not called. My question is, why does the "T-Plus: %d\n" while loop print not be called after the printf() function?:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char getString();
void tcount(void);


int main(void)
{
    tcount();
}

void tcount(void)
{
    // class scanf user input
    printf("%s", getString());

    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        printf("T-Plus: %d\n", i);
        i++;
    } while( i < 51 );
}

char getString()
{
    char name;
    printf("Please a string name: \n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    return name;
}
```

Now when I run it, this becomes the output:

```
$ ./namecount
Please a string name:
whoa
```

but the T-Plus: string does not get called.

Comment: `getstring` looks like it's clobbering memory. You're trying to read a string into a single character.

Comment: Um... you're using a `scanf()` format of `%s`, but only passing it a pointer to a single character. Hello undefined behavior, because entering even a single character is going to cause writing out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here:

1) In function `getString()` you are trying to read/scan a string in a char, you need memory to store the string and a terminating char, so you can use either of these two ways

Use a char array e.g. `char name[50];` or

Use a char pointer and
   allocate memory using malloc e.g.
 `char *p_name = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);`

2) You are then trying to return this string which is stored in local variable (which would get destroyed as soon as function ends) so you should use the second approach (use malloc) and return the pointer.

So your code would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * getString();
void tcount(void);


int main(void)
{
    tcount();
}

void tcount(void)
{
    // class scanf user input
    char *p_name = getString();
    printf("%s", p_name);
    free(p_name);

    int i = 1;
    do  
    {   
        printf("T-Plus: %d\n", i); 
        i++;
    } while( i < 51 );
}

char *getString()
{
    char *p_name = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    printf("Please a string name: \n");
    scanf("%s", p_name);
    return p_name;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", p_name);` is as bad a `gets()`.  Recommend a width limit: `scanf("%49s", p_name);`

Comment: I tried compiling your way and it raised a segmentation fault (core dumped) and two warnings:
a.) initialization of 'char *' from char makes a pointer from integer without a cast.
b.) returning 'char *' from function with return type 'char' makes integer from pointer without a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer did not work, Okay so I've edited the code like this, it compiles fine. But raises a segmentation fault though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * getString();
void tcount(void);

int main(void)
{
    tcount();
}

void tcount(void)
{
    // class scanf user input
    char *name = getString();
    printf("%s", name);
    free(name);

    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        printf("T-Plus: %d\n", i);
        i++;
    } while( i < 51 );
}


char * getString()
{
    char *p_name[50];
    printf("Please a string name: \n");
    scanf("%49s", (char *) &p_name);
    return *p_name;
}
```

When the program is run, it asks for your input but still raises a Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: That's because `getString` does not return anything although it should return a `char *`. I have updated my post with updated code.